# More information about error in node-red

Tags: raspberry-pi3, raspbian, node-red

when I start node-red and get error I get information about the error and in which function and file it happen.

```
For example "6 Apr 12:54:56 - [error] [function:sendConfBLE] TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"
```

But what when I want information about precise line which this error did.

There is any option to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The VM module used by the node-red function node doesn't expose any more details of the error.